# Eclipse PDT Launch HTML,JS Files in browser

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse-pdt, launch

Is there a way to Launch HTML and JS Files in a web browser in Eclipse PDT? Currently, it only launches PHP Files, else, the "Unable to Lauch" dialog appears? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the file, select Open Width -> Browser.  You may need to setup which browser to use under your preferences

Answer (score 0):

I found it at last! Go to **External Tools Configurations**, create new configuration. In **Main** tab, Enter the path to your browser application (ex. /usr/bin/firefox) as **Location**, then enter "http://localhost${resource_path}" (if your using a local server) in **Arguments**.